# VBA Word format mergefield

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mergefield

I have a fieldfunction that formats a given number (price) from an excel table.

i.e.:

```
Fieldname = FieldName & " \# #.##0,00 USD"
```

It works, but if the value is less than a thousand, the hashes and the point are read as spaces.

How can I remove or prevent the spaces to show up in the word file?

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand how your code could work at all. What is in "Fieldname". Why would concatenating "Fieldname" with the string " \# #.##0,00 USD" do anything useful?

Answer (score 2):

Too many `#` in format..try this:

```
 Fieldname = FieldName & " \# #.#0,00 USD"
```

Just for further clarification, I didn't really know how the code above used in mergefield by questioner..usually formatting mergefield look like this:

```
 {MERGEFIELD  ANum \# "#.#0,00 USD"}
```